# C# Roslyn определить что класс относится к текущей сборке, а не сторонней библиотеки

Tags: c#, roslyn

как используя Roslyn определить что класс относится к текущей сборке, а не сторонней библиотеки, весь день пробовал различные варианты, но так и не понял как это сделать
Пробовал так и через Assebly.Load

```cs
// получаем текущую компиляцию
var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(orgDocument.FilePath));

// получаем синтаксическое дерево для класса MyClass
var syntaxTree = SyntaxFactory.ParseSyntaxTree(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(orgDocument.FilePath));

// добавляем синтаксическое дерево в компиляцию
compilation = compilation.AddSyntaxTrees(syntaxTree);

// получаем ссылку на класс MyClass
var classType = compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("MyClass.Example");
if (classType == null)
{
    return newRoot;
}
```

но classType всегда возвращает null